# Cassandra - Poor Query Performance using NetworkTopologyStrategy

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, nosql

Having performance issues using NetworkTopologyStrategy on a production keyspace with replication factor 4 across multiple datacenters (DCs located in 4 worldwide locations). Each DC has 3 nodes with pretty good hardware (70GB RAM, 5TB SSDs, etc.).

Same keyspace performs well in a SimpleStrategy using 4 node cluster in AWS, but running same queries in Production environment results in poor query times (select * from my_table is 6ms in AWS and 271ms in production).

Table "my_table" (name changed for privacy) is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    rec_type text,
    group_id int,
    rec_id timeuuid,
    user_id int,
    content text,
    created_on timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((rec_type, group_id), rec_id)
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.1
AND comment = ''
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
AND caching = {
    'keys' : 'ALL',
    'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'
}
AND compression = {
    'sstable_compression' : 'LZ4Compressor'
}
AND compaction = {
    'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'
};
```

This is a newly-created table in Production with occasional updates and low tombstone count.

Query trace is below:

[image]

Looks like range requests are taking the most amount of time. What would be the cause of the delay?

Network latency between nodes in the same DC is <1ms and latency between DCs is around 50-60ms.

EDIT:

Below is the query trace for a select * from my_table where rec_type = 'abc' and group = 1 LIMIT 300 query (2 screenshots because trace is so long):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hopefully you are not considering running `select * from table` queries as part of your transactional workload. select * will require responses from nodes on your entire ring and will incur network latencies. You should be using targeted where requests.

Comment: Right, select * was just a simple test since the table is currently small (25-50 rows). Performance is comparable with a where clause.

Comment: The performance may be comparable, but the query behavior is very different. Please provide a trace with the WHERE clause. Also, what consistency level are you using? If your'e doing a read that touches all 4 datacenters, speed of light will be a factor.

Comment: @JeffJirsa Query trace added for query with where clause. Consistency level is two (not local quorum). Tried local quorum and result was the same.

Comment: Will also add that the IPs are blacked out, but are all part of the same DC.

Comment: In your follow up traces it looks like you are getting 2ms

Comment: @RussS The total is 1757ms for one query (two screenshots make up one query trace)

Comment: That column is in microSeconds not milliseconds.

Comment: @RussS You are correct. The problem must be on the networking side, since query results took much longer than 1757 microseconds to be returned.